# Is there a way mapping ListProperties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I'm trying to map a ListProperties attribute of a class using JPA Hibernate. I searched a lot and decided to ask this question in here. I'm new using JPA and Hibernate, if I violate a rule, sorry for that, i'm taking my chance.

Is there a way to map and use ListProperties? If you wonder why I don't use List instead of List, I have a project that I need to implement database controls with JPA and Hibernate. Also, this project is implemented with maven, and using mariaDB is a must.

Student.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")

public class Student{

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@NotNull
private int id;

@Column(name = "text")
@NotNull
private String text;

@ElementCollection
@JoinColumn(name = "s_no")
private ListProperty<String> sList;

public Student(String text) {

    this.text = text;
    sList = new SimpleListProperty<String>();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public ObservableList<String> getsList() {
    return sList.get();
}

public ListProperty<String> sListProperty() {
    return sList;
}

public void setsList(ObservableList<String> sList) {
    this.sList.set(sList);
}
```

I get this error below when I run

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: model.Student.sList
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:324)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1899)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:913)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:740)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at controller.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:24)
```